# Microsoft Interop Excel. COM Exception with Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, .net, com, windows-server-2003, excel-interop

I deployed a VS.Net 2003 web application on Windows Server 2003 where Microsoft Office is not installed.  Everything works except Excel report functionality.  It's fine in my development PC where I have MS office.  The exception is:

> COM object with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is either
>   not valid or not registered.

Is there a way to get around this error without MS Office installation on the server? Any Office run-time components to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the COM Interop interacts directly with components of Excel. The only run-time components I know of are the Interop ones that let you use an installed copy of Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the information Chris.  Let me see to this.  I don't know how possible it is for me to request an install on the server. :-)

Comment: No problem. I looked in to running Office on a web server once to do some document mail-merges but only found a lot of reasons not to do that - in the end, a third-party library turned out to be be best option for us. It was by a company called Aspose. Think they do some Excel components too, although of course COM Interop won't work for these.